# Fran De Aquino's theories on gravity and electromagnetism; reputable?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-gravity, time-dilation

I've been transiently interested in the research of a Brazilian physicist named Fran De Aquino. The majority of his papers are related to gravity manipulation, which raises a lot of red flags. This man claims to have known the secret to anti gravity since the late 90's, and is employed by a college on Brazil as a professor. I've also read some rumors about him working for the United States government, but nothing necessarily believable. Most importantly, if he's correct, why haven't we done anything with this? And if he's wrong, why is he still publishing (and even able to publish) papers about this after 30 years? If he is wrong it's most likely a more psychological issue, but that's beside the point.

In his papers he often cites one of his earlier publications that outlines the fundamental principle of his theory. The idea is that the emitted and absorbed electromagnetic radiation of a particle factors directly into its momentum, and therefore can be exploited to bring about a negative value for the relativistic mass by significantly lowering the frequency of the electromagnetic waves emitted and absorbed. He's published numerous possible experiments to prove this is true, and they seem fairly easy to actually perform. This sounds to me like it would cause some significant effects were it true, like local time distortion.

This seems bogus to me, but I'm hopeful that one of you kind intelligent souls could look over some of his work and help me sleep easier about this all.

All his work can be found easily through google, though arxiv is an especially good website to use. I will link this one specific document because it should include everything really needed to make a judgement call on his theory. In all honesty I just don't understand the calculus used well enough to make a stance one way or the other.

[Mathematical Foundations of the Relativistic Theory of Quantum Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0212033)

Thanks!

Comment: This preprint has been revised 44 times (!) over the course of 12 years, which is more than I personally have ever seen.

Comment: That's really interesting, I didn't even notice. I wonder what they changed...

Comment: Well, if you really want to know, the other 43 versions of the paper should still be accessible by clicking on the version number.

Comment: This paper was published in a journal put out by an unaccredited university. This is not auspicious.

Comment: A cursory skim of the concluding pages yields "According to Eq. (131), imaginary  energy  is equal to psychic energy.  Consequently, the imaginary space-time is, in fact, the   psychic space-time, which contains the Supreme Consciousness. Since the Supreme  Consciousness has infinite psychic mass, then the psychic space-time has infinite psychic energy. This is highly relevant, because it confers to the psychic space-time the characteristic of unlimited source of energy."  @G.Smith Inauspicious, indeed.

Comment: The OP raises an interesting question: How does this qualify for arXiv?

Comment: @J.Murray Jesus, I hadn't gotten to that part yet.

Comment: Polite verdict: “Non-mainstream”. Voting to close as such.

Comment: If you have to ask...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things start to go wrong very early on, when he assumes that the gravitational field of a relativistic point mass is isotropic, which happens when he defines the potential $\phi=-\frac{GM_g}{r}$. This is wrong; Newtonian gravity simply doesn't extend to relativistic objects this way.

A full treatment of what happens to gravity at speeds approaching $c$ must involve general relativity; if you're looking at the gravitational field of a relativistic object of low mass, you can use [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism), which is a weak-field approximation of general relativity. In gravitoelectromagnetism, the gravitational force on an object is split into two components: the "gravitoelectric" field, which is close to what you would expect from the Newtonian gravitational field, and the "gravitomagnetic" field, which is a velocity-dependent force like the magnetic field. The behavior of these two fields is described by a set of equations reminiscent of Maxwell's Equations.

Gravitoelectromagnetism predicts that the "Newtonian-like" part of the gravitational field of a fast-moving object will behave like the electric field of a fast-moving charge: it will compress into a "pancake" centered on the plane transverse to the motion of the object. This makes the gravitational field of a moving object direction-dependent, meaning that the potential must depend not only on $r$, but also on $\theta$.

It all goes downhill from there.

Comment: I think I need to add emphasis: it goes _really really_ downhill. This first issue is quite minor compared to everything that comes afterward.

Comment: @knzhou Yeah, I'm wondering if I should talk about a more major issue instead, especially since I'm learning now that GEM doesn't seem to actually be Lorentz-invariant, so it isn't the relativistic weak-field analogue of gravity that I thought it was.

Comment: I found the psychic business. As when I was young I read a lot of metaphysics it gave me an "aha". See this, to see that fine minds do think of metaphysics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bfcOqD6ggk . The downhill is from mainstream physics

Comment: @knzhou Have you seen other papers like this on arXiv?

Comment: @knzhou  I think if the mathematics is correct according to the premises in the paper  , it is allowed,  Maybe this explains the many corrections

Comment: the last was for @G.Smith

Comment: @G.Smith Yes. It's not very hard to post on arXiv, since my understanding is that once you've gotten permission you have it for life. The arXiv moderators do exercise some discretion by moving sketchy papers to "General Physics" or "Popular Physics", which is precisely what happened here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment from an experimental physics physicist, into an answer so it will not be removed .

The fact that the papers are kept in arxiv ensures a minimum of mathematical consistency. It is not peer reviewed but there are basic standards kept.

The basic question to be answered is not whether the mathematics of the proposal are correct, and whether the fits to data claimed in the papers are correct, but on how inclusive are those fits.

The data in particle physics in particular are many and growing, and they are almost all encapsulated in the current [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. This means that any mathematical model claiming towards a theory of everything **must embed the standard model**. AFAIK it is only string theories that can do so. From the abstract of the paper you link there is no such claim made.

Mathematics is a wonderful field by itself, but it is a tool for the study of Nature. If his mathematics is correct, which I suspect it is, it is probably a transformation/projection for the specific data it fits, from the future Theory Of Everything. Similar to the way different series expansions can end up in fitting the same data.

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually read the paper.

Comment: @probably_someone  no, of course, too many formulae. I cannot do a peer review, As I say this is just a general comment and I have had too many general comments deleted lately. it is ok being downvoted.

Comment: On the first page De Aquino wrote “ The correlation between a and can be established based on the fact, that on the limit c → ∞...”. Anna, is this a Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler It is not reasonable within mainstream physics at present, but it is a mathematical assumption.. I think everybody agrees it is not mainstream physics